# C - Casting "h_addr_list" array to type "struct in_addr **"

Tags: c, unix, struct, casting, network-programming

I'm reading this tutorial: [here](http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/) But I can't understand how this part works. Casting from `char**` to a `struct in_addr **` that contains an `unsigned long` seems weird.

```
// Cast the h_addr_list to in_addr 
// since h_addr_list also has the ip address in long format only
addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;
```

I wish someone could explain what's happening and how the code works.

**EDIT:** To be more specific: I want to know how can the compiler understand what we are trying to do here ? why should this code be correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `gethostbyname`, it returns a pointer to a `struct hostent`.  One of the fields in this struct, `h_addr_list`, is an array of pointers to network addresses.

Since a network address can be either a `struct in_addr` for an IPv4 address or a `struct in6_addr` for an IPv6 address, `h_addr_list` is defined as a `char **` as a generic type that can point to either one.  The `h_addrtype` field tells you which one of these is valid.

Once you know that, you cast `h_addr_list` to either `struct in_addr **` or `struct in6_addr **` as appropriate, then access each element in the array.

EDIT:

Pointers between either `void` or `char` types and any other non-function type can freely be casted to or from each other.

In this particular case, it's likely that `gethostbyname` has a static `char` buffer that it casts to a `struct in_addr **` or a `struct in6_addr **` as appropriate in order to create the array.  Then the calling function performs the same cast in order to get the values out.

Comment: I understand this point, the problem is how this cast works ? It's kinda weird, How the compiler understands it ?

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg See my edit.  Hopefully that makes things more clear.